# Could you suggest books, papers or problems that could be used as good "general" motivating examples of calculus application?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, recreational-mathematics

I would like to stress the kind of reference I am looking for... In statistics there are lots of motivating (and sometimes unexpected) examples that are interested for everyone such as [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), [Simpson Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox), [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), [St Petersburg Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) that easily motivate people from different fields. I love the examples that come from physics or economics, but usually they are usually interested only for students of engineering (or physics) and economics.

Suggestions of papers from American Mathematical Monthly, American Scientist or periodicals which are specialized in teaching are very welcome!

Comment: This article might help a bit? http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/for-calculus-students-what-should-be-the-intuition-or-motivation-behind-series
Also if you asked the question there too, you'd probably get some good answers!

Comment: Great question! Is it an acceptable policy to ask the same question in different math forums?